# AzureStaticWebApp fails on triggerUncaughtException at playwright

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops, playwright

> On running the AzureStaticWebApp recently there was node and npm
> upgradation which caused a promise error i.e triggerUncaughtException
> as shown below in error, which causing exit code 1. How can I resolve
> this error which did not occur earlier. Also there was peer
> dependencies error which was resolved by adding **legacy-peer-deps=true**
> in .env file

```
  npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
    npm WARN While resolving: @date-io/date-fns@1.1.0
    npm WARN Found: date-fns@2.29.3
    npm WARN node_modules/date-fns
    npm WARN   date-fns@"^2.29.3" from the root project
    npm WARN   2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, @date-io/date-fns)
    npm WARN 
    npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
    npm WARN peer date-fns@"2.0.0-alpha.27" from @date-io/date-fns@1.1.0
    npm WARN node_modules/@date-io/date-fns
    npm WARN   @date-io/date-fns@"1.1.0" from material-table@1.69.3
    npm WARN   node_modules/material-table
    npm WARN 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@material-ui/pickers, material-table)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 

    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /working_dir/TodoList/TodoList.Client/node_modules/playwright
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
    npm ERR! node:internal/process/promises:288
    npm ERR!             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
    npm ERR!             ^
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.cache/ms-playwright'] {
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
    npm ERR!   path: '/root/.cache/ms-playwright'
    npm ERR! }
    npm ERR!
```

> can **node-options="--unhandled-rejections=warn"** in .npmrc file  or
> **NODE_OPTIONS=--unhandled-rejections=warn** in .env file resolve the
> above uncaught exception error
>
> playwright test case -

```
test.describe("Playwright web page accessibility test for home screen", () => {
  test.beforeEach(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(ENV.BASE_URL);
    await injectAxe(page);
  });

  test("simple accessibility run for home screen", async () => {
    await checkA11y(page, null, axeOption);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the version dis-match of Node and packages after upgradation.

I believe this could resolve your issue

> Also there was peer dependencies error which was resolved by adding
> legacy-peer-deps=true in .env file

Another good approach could be Adding `--legacy-peer-deps` into `- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0`

Sample:

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/'
      api_location: 'api'
      app_build_command: 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'
      output_location: ''
      api_build_command: 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```